# Solve a nonlinear system of equations with C/C++

Tags: systems-of-equations, math-software

My system of equations is like this:

```
(x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 = c1
(x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 = c2
```

I know it is simple using Matlab:

```
solve((x-a1)^2 + (y-b1)^2 - c1, (x-a2)^2 + (y-b2)^2 - c2)
```

But how to solve this problem using C/C++? I know a math library [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/index.html), but is for linear equations. Any suggestions?

Comment: `solve` is in Matlab's Symbolic Math toolbox. Do you actually need C/C++ for computer algebra (symbolic math) or are you perhaps just using the wrong function in Matlab?

Comment: Yes. I need c/c++ because I have to embed this algorithm to the old system written in c/c++. I can get the numeric value from `solve` function with `vpa`.

Comment: That wasn't my question. Can you solve your problem numerically using double precision floating-point (e.g., `fsolve`) rather than symbolic math and variable precision algebra? The two use entirely different approaches, have very different performances in terms of speed, and different potential precisions. Maybe I should ask: do you have specific numeric values for your constants `a1`, `b1`, `c1`, etc. or are they arbitrary unknowns. Also, your specific example has an analytic solution so I assume that you're dealing with a more complex system

Comment: Yes, `a1`, `b1`, `c1` and `a2`, `b2`, `c2` all have specific numeric values (you can think them as: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). I really want to solve more general system than this.

Comment: I would recommend just analytically solving your system if all you need to do is the above equations. If you need more general systems, you are going to need a library. Secant method (1 variable) or gradient descent (multiple variables) come to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need to be using symbolic math in Matlab in the first place. If your parameters are given in terms of floating-point values and you're ultimately interested in obtaining a floating-point value as a result, numeric methods should be your first choice (there are reasons to use symbolic approaches, but I'm not going to discuss this here). For your example, you need a multi-dimensional nonlinear root-solver. In Matlab, `fsolve` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html)) performs this function. You should probably start by ensuring that you can solve your problem in Matlab using this function – here's an example:

```
a = [1 2];
b = [3 4];
c = [5 6];
f = @(x)[(x(1)-a(1)).^2 + (x(2)-b(1)).^2-c(1);...
         (x(1)-a(2)).^2 + (x(2)-b(2)).^2-c(2)];
x0 = [1;1]; % Initial guess
opts  = optimset('Display','iter')
[x,fx] = fsolve(f,x0,opts)
```

which returns a single root with coordinates at

```
x =

   2.811249499748931
   1.688750500251424
```

Note that for these parameters, this system has multiple roots, but numeric methods generally only return one root. By adjusting the initial guess (here `x0`) or using using more advanced constrained optimization, the other roots can be found.

Matlab's `fsolve` uses a [trust region method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_region) by default, the [Trust-Region Dogleg method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/equation-solving-algorithms.html#f51887). In some cases the solver automatically switches algorithms with a warning message an you can specify the algorithm to use via [`optimset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/optimset.html). Find the algorithm that works best for your problem.

As for C/C++, there are a variety of options. The [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) has [support for multi-dimensional root-finding](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Multidimensional-Root_002dFinding.html#Multidimensional-Root_002dFinding). You might look for code that implements the same or similar algorithm as you're using in `fsolve`. For example, it appears that [MINPACK](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/minpack/minpack.html) implements a Powell dogleg algorithm similar to `fsolve`'s default method. There are many others, such as [PNL](http://pnl.gforge.inria.fr/docs/html/pnl-manualse13.html#x15-11900013) and the quite interesting-looking [O<sub>2</sub>scl](http://o2scl.sourceforge.net) ([documentation](http://o2scl.sourceforge.net/o2scl/html/solve_section.html)).